# Forge viewer model position after transformation

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've used the [Model transformation extension](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.Transform) to move the model from one point to another. Now How can I get the new location/coordinates/position of the transformed model or its bounding box as when I query the bounding box min and max points they are the same all the time. Any ideas??
My target is to get the new position of the model according to the origin after translation.

Answer (score 0):

I isolated the core section of that extension and check the position and bounding box before and after transformation. To be simple, only translate. It looks those values are updated after transformation. Could you check if it could help to diagnose your problem?

To test it, select one object and run the function.

```
getModifiedWorldBoundingBox (fragIds, fragList) {

   const fragbBox = new THREE.Box3()
   const nodebBox = new THREE.Box3()

  fragIds.forEach(function(fragId) {

     fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox)

     nodebBox.union(fragbBox)
  })

  return nodebBox
}

 $('#test').click(function(rt){

        var dbids = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection();
        var it = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;
        var fragList = NOP_VIEWER.model.getFragmentList();  

        fragIds = [];

        it.enumNodeFragments(dbids[0], function(fragId) {
            fragIds.push(fragId); 
        }, false);

        var bb = getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(fragIds,fragList);
        console.log('boundingbox before transform: [max,min]: ' + 
        bb.max.x + ' ' + bb.max.y + ' ' + bb.max.z + '\n'+ 
        bb.min.x + ' ' + bb.min.y + ' ' + bb.min.z ); 

        fragIds.forEach(function(fragId){ 

            var fragProxy = NOP_VIEWER.impl.getFragmentProxy(
            NOP_VIEWER.model,
            fragId)

            fragProxy.getAnimTransform()

            console.log('frag position in LCS before transform:' + 
                            fragProxy.position.x + ','+
                            fragProxy.position.y + ','+ 
                            fragProxy.position.z);

            var wcsMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); 
            fragProxy.getWorldMatrix(wcsMatrix);
            var wcsPos = wcsMatrix.getPosition();
            console.log('frag position in wcs matrix  before transform: ' + 
            wcsPos.x + ' ' + wcsPos.y + ' ' + wcsPos.z);


            fragProxy.position.x += 10; 
            fragProxy.position.y += 10; 
            fragProxy.position.z += 10;   

            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()  
        }); 
        NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneUpdated(true) 


        fragIds.forEach(function(fragId){ 

            var fragProxy = NOP_VIEWER.impl.getFragmentProxy(
            NOP_VIEWER.model,
            fragId)

            fragProxy.getAnimTransform()

            console.log('frag position in LCS after transform:' + 
                            fragProxy.position.x + ','+
                            fragProxy.position.y + ','+ 
                            fragProxy.position.z); 

            var wcsMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); 
            fragProxy.getWorldMatrix(wcsMatrix);
            var wcsPos = wcsMatrix.getPosition();
            console.log('frag position in wcs matrix  after transform: ' + 
            wcsPos.x + ' ' + wcsPos.y + ' ' + wcsPos.z);
        }); 

        bb = getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(fragIds,fragList);
        console.log('boundingbox after transform: [max,min]: ' + 
        bb.max.x + ' ' + bb.max.y + ' ' + bb.max.z + '\n'+ 
        bb.min.x + ' ' + bb.min.y + ' ' + bb.min.z ); 

    });
```

Comment: Dear Xiaodon, thanks for the answer. 
Actually this is not the solution I'm looking for. 
My workflow should be something like this:
1 - I transform the models.
2 - I use the use the viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels() to get a list of loaded models
3 - Using Iteration I get the bounding box of each model.
As per your solution I don't need to iterate through all the fragments as this will consume a lot of time, I just need the current position of the whole model (like insertion point).

Comment: I need something like getRootElement() then getPosition()

Comment: As I know, the original data (viewer.model.getData()) will not be updated if the model/object is transformed. it looks the only way to get the updated position will depend on checking the proxy of fragments, as my code does. OR, you could set the updated matrix to Javascript object model. e.g. model.transform = XXX every time when the model is transformed.

Comment: I try to perform this solution just for fun, but it says - getModifiedWorldBoundingBox is not defined. Which is truly are. You do not define it, and it's not available in references extension. As well in Viewer3D.js is also not. Maybe in Three.js?

Comment: @MikhailKh My apology! I even forgot to enclose this function :(  getModifiedWorldBoundingBox . It is available now. It is just a help function we defined for this workflow. Thank you for pointing out!